# SQL-CLR stored procedure doesn't return value

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlclr, clrstoredprocedure

I looked through Stackoverflow and found almost identical [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070403/clr-stored-procedure-return-value-null). It was asked a year ago and nobody answered it yet. Maybe I'll be more lucky than user1038334 and somebody will help me.

I have a SQL CLR stored procedure which works fine for days until something weird happens. My stored proc updates tables and returns a value as a result code. So by looking at this value I can decide if something went wrong. The problem is in receiving this result value. C# code throws an exception at a point of receiving a return value.

```
var returnValue = new SqlParameter {Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue};
command.Parameters.Add(returnValue);

connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

return (int)returnValue.Value; //<-- here is an exception
```

And the funniest thing is that if I connect SQL Profiler, catch the query and then execute this query inside of SQL Server Management Studio I still can get a result value without any problems:

```
DECLARE @RC INT
EXECUTE @RC = MyClrStoreProc
SELECT @RC
```

Once I republish the CLR assembly or restart SQL Server everything gets fixed.

I'm pretty sure there should be a reason for such weird behaviour but I can't find.

- SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server Developer Edition (64-bit) - v.10.50.1765.0
- Host OS version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1 (7601)
- .Net version: v4.0.30319

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you got command.CommandType set to?

Comment: Can you reproduce it if you run [sp_recompile](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2536225)?

Comment: @AdaTheDev: My command type is set to CommandType.StoredProcedure.

Comment: @Anurag Ranjhan: I don't know the answer as the issue doesn't happen all the time. But I will definitely check it once it occurs again.

Comment: @AnuragRanjhan: Sorry for misunderstanding. Before I looked into your [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2536225) I thought you were asking to run sp_recompile once problem had occured. But now I see you pointed out the right solution for my case. And I have to say one thing though. SP_RECOMPILE was not causing the problem. I tried another way to cause store proc recompilation: "DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS;" and only that one caused the described issue. I already asked our dba to install SPs. Will get back later and update about state of my problem. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a SQL Server bug and [Cumulative Update package 8](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2536225) fixes the issue.